# What is the Error in below python code segment which is trying to print prime numbers

Tags: python-3.x

```
num = int(input("Enter the number:"))
Max_div = int(num / 2)
print("------------Max_div:",Max_div)
div = int(2)
counter = 1
while div <= Max_div:
    if num % div  == 0:
       break
    else:
       counter = counter + 1
       print("before the flood",counter)
       continue
       print("after the flood")

    print("div:/tMax_div",div,Max_div)
    div = div + 1

print("Div out of loop",div)    
div = div - 1
if div == Max_div:
   print("Prime")
else:
   print("Not Prime")
```

This code (of finding prime number) work fine if I delete else block(of while loop). Not sure what continue statement is doing here. Where is it getting stuck actually? 
assuming indentation is correct !

Comment: Python is indentation sensitive, and your code does not appear to be indented correctly. Can you ensure the indentation matches your actual source code, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code can be something like this:

```
num = int(input("Enter the number:"))
Max_div = int(num / 2)
print("------------Max_div:",Max_div)
div = int(2)
while div <= Max_div:
    if num % div  == 0:
        break
    else:
        div = div + 1
        print("before the flood",div)  #
        continue
        print("after the flood")  #

print("div:/tMax_div",div,Max_div)  #
div = div + 1    #
print("Div out of loop",div)    #
div = div - 1    #
if div > Max_div:
    print("Prime")
else:
    print("Not Prime")
```

Notice that you can delete all of the lines with the # at the end and the program still works well. The `continue` expression terminates that iteration of loop however unlike the `break` statement the loop continues doing its next iteration.